# How do i acess the values and keys of a <string, vector<string>> map?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to access the keys and variables of my map:

```
map<string, vector<string>> Di;
```

so that i can see if the value contains a name and in that case what the key(number) is for that value.
i have tried this but i only got this far and i don't know where to go from here:

```
for (auto& kv : Di)
{
    bool checking = Di.find(namn) != Di.end();
    if (checking)
    {
        string key = Di.first;
        cout<<"Number: "<<key<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the elements of the map, then use the keywords `first` and `second` to access the key and value respectively.

```
for (auto const& element : Di)
{
    string key = element.first;
    vector<string> value = element.second;
}
```

If you are looking for a specific element in your map, you can just do

```
map<string, vector<string>>::iterator it = Di.find(name);
if (it != end(Di)
{
    vector<string> value = it->second;
}
```